# AMD Radeon R9 graphics card won't display my second screen

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, amd-radeon

I have recently built a new Windows 8.1 gaming PC and I am using the AMD Radeon R9 280 Black Double Dissipation Edition.  It works a treat except I seem to have an issue whereby I cannot get my second screen running.

I installed the latest drivers but it was to no avail.  I use two DVI to VGA cable from the graphics card to the two monitors in question but only one of the monitors is displayed.

I have gone through all of the settings of the Catalyst software but I can't find anything to enable the monitor.  I also tried switching the cables around to see if I had a faulty cable; I don't the both work.

I would really appreciate it if anybody could help me out in this issue and if you need me to provide any additional info I can do so.

Thanks, Carty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your [XFX Radeon R9 280 Double Dissipation Edition](http://xfxforce.com/en-us/products/amd-radeon-r9-series/amd-radeon-r9-280-black-double-dissipation-edition-r9-280a-tdbd) video card only has one DVI-I connection.  The other DVI connection is DVI-D and can't be adapted to VGA.

> Output - DL-*DVI-I* : 1
>
> Output - HDMI : 1
>
> Output - mini DP : 1
>
> Output - SL-*DVI-D* : 1

However, you could use the Mini DisplayPort connection for VGA using an [adapter like this one](http://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-to-VGA-Adapter-Converter-Mini-DP-to-VGA-1920x1200~MDP2VGA2).

Comment: Thank you for your quickly reply.  I have purchased the other DVI cable, so hopefully that will work like a charm.  It's a shame that there aren't more connections from it; ah well.

Comment: @Carty You're welcome.  Please mark this as an answer if you feel it's appropriate.  Also, it's recommended to use DVI cables instead of VGA where possible.

Comment: My cable just arrived and it works a treat, I have two monitors! :D  The only thing is is that the second monitor doesn't show the correct resolution on the list...